# Can I ask for RAM of container exceed the physical memory on the single host with Docker-Swarm

Tags: docker, cluster-computing, docker-swarm

I'm new to docker,and I want to build a docker cluster with docker-swarm.

In the link:https://docs.docker.com/swarm/scheduler/strategy/ I have a question:

Suppose I have 2 nodes with 2G RAM.What if I run a container ask for 3G RAM.Will it work?

Or there's another method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not set any [user memory constraints](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user-memory-constraints) at runtime, the process will be able to use as much memory as it wants, eventually swapping to disk like any other process would when there is no free physical memory on the host.

Comment: Hi,Andy,thanks.So is it impossible to assign total 3G RAM to both node1 and node2?For instance,node1 and node2 each assign to 1.5G ram?Under docker-swarm cluster.